# Append a HTML tag to dynamically created DOM in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular-datatables

I have table header that is dynamically created , how can I access it using the class name and append a HTML tag along with it in pure angular way

**Before**

```
<div class="column-header">Header</div>
```

**After**

```
<div class="column-header">Header<span>Some value</span></div>
```

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild, OnInit, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({ selector: 'column-header' })
export class ColumnDirective implements OnInit {
    elem: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {
      this.elem=el;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const span1 = "<span class='mytooltip ico-help fa fa-question-circle'>";
    const span2 = "<span class='tooltiptext'>Question</span>";
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.renderer.appendChild(span1,span2);
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, span1);
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

I dont want to use any jquery to append tags ,I tried following the above approach but it didnt help. Is there a angular way of performing the desired outcome ?

Comment: How is your directive related to the HTML in **Before** and **After**?

Comment: its the before div's class name @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Your code doesn't show that. Please update your question.

Comment: done , sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems in the approach you took, namely declaring a

`const span1 = "<span class='mytooltip ico-help fa fa-question-circle'>";`

It will not help you create an HTML tag. It will be just a simple string and nothing else.

Here is what you can try:

First id your 'div' tag, which is holding the header:

```
<div #header1>Header </div>
```

Once You have it, all you need to do is read this element in you TypeScript file using a '@ViewChild' as below:

```
@ViewChild('header1') d1: ElementRef;
```

@ViewChild is an elegant typescript way to get any html dom from the code and use it in your code.
Once you are done with getting the element in your code, all you need to do is append your code to this as below:

```
this.d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span>Some value</span>');
```

Comment: Can we try it with class name rather than id ? because i cant assign id to dynamically created DOM

Comment: my table has an id #mytable but i cant have one for table header

Comment: The Idea of accessing an element with an ID is to get the unique DOM tree associated with it. You can definetily load it with a class name, as long as that`s a single class associated in your code. In your case you are going to append it to a 'div' tag, which makes it difficult to access, as there probably will be thousands of 'div' tags. I might be able to help you more, in case you share how you are dynamically generating the header??

Comment: https://hjalmers.github.io/angular-generic-table/advanced , am currently making use of this data table , but am not able to append any HTML tags to the column headers , thats the issue

Comment: I don`t think using a generic table will help you with what you want to achieve as 1) It only accepts Column Name from you and then renders it to the Generic Table internally. 2) The Input Column Name, you give are mere strings, which are associated to the column name later.

Comment: What you really want is a a table in which you can access the Header component. Something like MatTable might help you in such situation. Using MatTable you can generate the complete table dynamically, also you will have the control over the entire column, and the Header. Each of it can be accessed as an ElementRef

Comment: The finally structure of generic table also resembles a table right ? in that case i should be able to access it ?